# CRASH: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

I am getting an array out of bounds error at this ridiculous index, which based on my research says that there is probably some code calling something negative such as `[array objectAtIndex: -1]`  Problem is that this isn't my code and I cannot find it anywhere.  I have put breakpoints all over the place to no avail.  I am thinking it may be in a UITableView Delegate method but can't be certain.  Is there anyway to access the value of all my int variables in the log.  I can't NSLog them because I don't know where the crash is occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the stack trace you get at the error. Which of your functions is most recent (i.e. closest to the top of the list)? That's where the problem will lie.

Comment: try to find the NSMutablearray in your code which loads the table with array contents, but when you try to pull out an index with negative value then it crashes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding an exception breakpoint to see if this catches it:

1) Click on the breakpoints tab

2) Click on the "+" button on bottom left of said tab screen

3) Select "Add Exception Breakpoint"

4) (Optional) change Exception:All to Exception:Objective-C

5) Click done

This typically will break right on/before the line that's causing the crash.

Good luck.

Comment: Found it, an int variable was being subtracted by another int variable causing a negative number.  I would vote this up 10 if I could!  Thank you!

Comment: I would like to give you +10 if I could, I'm new to XCode and obj-c and I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out what was causing my exception!  gracias

Comment: Simply great option...vital for survival

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an exception breakpoint
2. Check the stack trace
   [image]
3. find the last method executed
4. Log the value used for getting array value