# [_NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0..1]

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

I'm using a simulator for iphone 4s(iOS 7.0.3) for my app and I get the following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x003085e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027568b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x002a94e6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
    3   Requisitions                        0x0015007a -[PasswordLoginController3 _adjustInputPos] + 61
    4   Requisitions                        0x0015042a -[PasswordLoginController3 keyboardWasShown:] + 312
    5   Foundation                          0x02428bf9 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00364524 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x002bc00b _CFXNotificationPost + 2859
    8   Foundation                          0x02362951 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    9   UIKit                               0x009ffb1b -[UIInputViewTransition postNotificationsForTransitionEnd] + 1054
    10  UIKit                               0x009f6138 __53-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]_block_invoke1332 + 455
    11  UIKit                               0x006993c0 -[UINavigationControllerKeyboardAnimationStyle launchAnimation:afterStarted:completion:forHost:fromCurrentPosition:] + 501
    12  UIKit                               0x009f5a7c -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:] + 1258
    13  UIKit                               0x009f7c0e -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1029
    14  UIKit                               0x009f8019 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animated:] + 72
    15  UIKit                               0x009f8063 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:] + 67
    16  UIKit                               0x009ef2fa -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1453
    17  UIKit                               0x006c969a -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] + 287
    18  UIKit                               0x006c8f8b -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 550
    19  UIKit                               0x005cc19b -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114
    20  UIKit                               0x00c4ce43 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
    21  UIKit                               0x005cc1e8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) deferredBecomeFirstResponder] + 67
    22  UIKit                               0x005cc27c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _promoteSelfOrDescendantToFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x005cc53e __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 224
    24  UIKit                               0x005cc388 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 260
    25  UIKit                               0x005d74c1 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1847
    26  UIKit                               0x005ca9b1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    27  UIKit                               0x00563848 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 1927
    28  UIKit                               0x005d13ef +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    29  UIKit                               0x00562c96 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1155
    30  UIKit                               0x0069de4e -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3446
    31  UIKit                               0x006aa0c7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    32  UIKit                               0x006aacb9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    33  UIKit                               0x007e4181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    34  UIKit                               0x005da267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    35  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0276881f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    36  QuartzCore                          0x022182ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    37  QuartzCore                          0x0220c0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    38  QuartzCore                          0x0220bf40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    39  QuartzCore                          0x02173ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    40  QuartzCore                          0x02174e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    41  QuartzCore                          0x02175544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x002d04ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x002d041f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x002ae344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x002adac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x002ad8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    47  GraphicsServices                    0x03ce39e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    48  GraphicsServices                    0x03ce3809 GSEventRun + 104
    49  UIKit                               0x0056fd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    50  Requisitions                        0x000a712c main + 92
    51  libdyld.dylib                       0x03036701 start + 1
    52  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I tried this thread [CRASH: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391561/crash-nsarraym-objectatindex-index-4294967295-beyond-bounds-0-9) and tried to debug at certain breakpoint, but no avail. I couldn't figure out where the issue is happening. Objective C is not my forte , but still fixing this issue.

Method _adjustInputPos

```
-(void) _adjustInputPos
{
    UITextField *currentField = [inputFields objectAtIndex:currentInputIndex];
    CGFloat currentInputHeight = currentField.frame.origin.y;
    UIView* v = [self.formView viewWithTag:70];
    if(v!=nil) {
        currentInputHeight += v.frame.origin.y;
    }
    UIScrollView* sv = (UIScrollView*)self.view;

    CGFloat offset = 0;
    if (sv.contentOffset.y>=(currentInputHeight)) {
        offset = (sv.frame.size.height-kbHeight)/1.5;
    } else if((self.view.frame.size.height-kbHeight-currentInputHeight)<currentField.frame.size.height) {
        offset = (sv.frame.size.height-kbHeight)/1.5;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    if(sv.contentOffset.y==offset) {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, offset);
    [sv setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

Method keyBoardWasShown

```
- (void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notf
{
    if(isHidden) {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *info = [notf userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    kbHeight = kbSize.height;
    BOOL islandscape = [[ClientAuthenticator getInstance].actionHandler isLandscape];
    if(!islandscape && [LSUtility isTablet]) {//ipad portrait,no need.
        return;
    }

    if(islandscape ) {
        kbHeight = kbSize.width;
    }

    if (is30Style) {
        [self _adjustInputPos];
    } else {
        [self _adjustInputPos31];
    }
    UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(sv.frame.size.width, sv.frame.size.height+kbHeight/1.5);
    [sv setContentSize:size];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Find which line. My guess is that you're trying to do `[anArray objectAtIndex:anIndex]` with anIndex not set.

Comment: It is UInt32 max, so it could be that you are calling the method with index -1

Comment: This is a simple one to debug and should not require a question here.  The index is obviously out of bounds and a negative number, since anything over 2-billion-something is negative.  The line number is identified and is in your module.  Go there, figure out why the index is wrong.

Comment: Did you switch to 64 bits as well?

Comment: One way to get this error is to cast a negative integer as (long)(uint32)(int32). On a 32 bit machine, this will work (but it is an error anyway. On 64 bits, this will make the calculations go wrong. Check carefully the two methods in PasswordLoginController, or post it here if you need help.

Comment: I have posted the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`4294967295` is `0xFFFFFFFF` in hex, or `-1` as an `unsigned int`.

Check in `[PasswordLoginController3 _adjustInputPos]` - it is asking for `objectAtIndex` with the value `-1` (which is out of bounds).

**Edit since you added code**

```
UITextField *currentField = [inputFields objectAtIndex:currentInputIndex]
```

This looks to be the line that the error comes from. What is the type of `currentInputIndex` and where is it initialised/modified?

Comment: This works fine in iOS8 , but throws that exception in iOS 7.03 or iOS 7.1, do you know any reason that might?

Comment: This part of code is from external library and when I debug, it doesn't show me any code, but machine code. How do I attach a source?

Comment: currentInputIndex is NSUInteger type and it is set to -1 in initWithNibName method.

Comment: That's your problem - you can't call objectAtIndex with a negative value.

Comment: @davbryn - I am not really able to debug that part of the code as it is a framework, so I am not sure why it is being set to -1. Why would it work without this error in iOS8 and not in IOS7.1?